# MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found in yii2

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using php7.1.5(latest) and add mongodb extension with the help of below link
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php. Using mongodb driver version as 1.2.9 add dll file in php/ext folder. I check phpinfo() mongodb extension is added. But when i access **mongodb** like below

> $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

It will throw error like MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found.

I try to add mongodb extension in php.ini file like below formats, but it will not work

> extension=php_mongodb.dll,
>   extension=mongodb.dll

i am using apache version 2.4.25

Comment: Added mongoDB extension not enough, You need to add https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb yii2 extension or php mongoDB https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library to your project. Just note: If you are on windows Os, PHP mongoDB extensions have Thread safe and Not Thread safe version, Its important on your choose.

Comment: thank you  Sajjad_Dehghani but problem is missing backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a backslash in front, as the class is in the Global Namespace and not under yii

`$mng = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");`

Comment: yes i already find out this,any way thank you for your reponse